# Scala - Make signature of function parameter f of higher order function g dependent on varars of g

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference, variadic-functions, higher-order-functions

I am trying to define a higher order function `f` which accepts a variable number of parameters `args` of type `Wrapper[T]*` and a function parameter `g` in Scala.

The function `f` should decapsulate each object passed in `args` and then call `g` with the decapsulated parameters. Therefore, `g` has to accept exactly the same number of parameters of type `T` as `args` contains.

The closest thing I could achieve was to pass a `Seq[T]` to `g` and to use pattern matching inside of `g`. Like the following:

```
f("This", "Is", "An", "Example")(x => x match {
  case Seq(a:String, b:String, c:String): //Do something.
})
```

With `f` defined like:

```
def f[V](args: Wrapper[T]*)
        (g: (Seq[T]) => (V)) : V = {
  val params = args.map(x => x.unwrap())
  g(params)
}
```

1. How is it possible to accomplish a thing like this without pattern
   matching?
2. It is possible to omit the types in the signature of `g`
   by using type inference, but only if the number of parameters is
   fixed. How could this be done in this case?
3. It is possible to pass
   different types of parameters into varargs, if a type wildcard is
   used `args: Wrapper[_]*`. Additionally, casting the result of
   `x.unwrap` to `AnyRef` and using pattern matching in `g` is
   necessary. This, however, completely breaks type inference and type
   safety. Is there a better way to make mixing types in the varargs
   possible in this special case?

I am also considering the use of scala makros to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: FYI `List(T) params = args.map(x => x.unwrap)` is not a valid scala code

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Tuples -> List easy, List -> Tuple not-easy. Perhaps [Shapless' HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) might do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I get you right? I replaced your `Wrapper` with some known type, but that doesn't seem to be essential.

```
def f[T, V](args: T*)(g: PartialFunction[Seq[T], V]): V = g(args)
```

So later you can do this:

```
f(1,2,3) { case Seq(a,b,c) => c } // Int = 3
```

Okay, I've made my own `Wrapper` to be totally clear:

```
case class Wrapper[T](val x:T) { 
  def unwrap = x 
}

def f[V](args: Wrapper[_]*)(g: PartialFunction[Seq[_], V]): V =
  g(args.map(_.unwrap))

f(Wrapper("1"), Wrapper(1), Wrapper(BigInt(1))) {
  case Seq(s: String, i: Int, b: BigInt) => (s, i, b)
} // res3: (String, Int, BigInt) = (1,1,1)
```

Regarding your concerns about type safety and conversions: as you can see, there aren't any explicit conversions in the code above, and since you are going to pattern-match with explicitly defined types, you may not to worry about these things - if some items of an undefined origin are going to show in your input, `scala.MatchError` will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, you got it right. This provides an answer to 3, if I understand it correctly (I can mix types and I don't have to worry about type safety when using pattern matching). Any Ideas for 1 & 2, too?